# Are there any limitations on Shopify Metaobjects?

Tags: shopify

I can't seem to find any developer documentation on Shopify Metaobject limits. Can we have an unlimited number of types/definitions and an unlimited number of ojects within each type? I'm sure we can't, so wondering if anyone knows what the limitations are.

Edit: I found that some Shopify Apps use MetaObjects and that Shopify is limiting the MetaObjects to 1000. However, I'm not sure if the limitation is per type or if we can just have a total of 1000.

Answer (score 0):

So far from documentation, it's not described any limitation regarding this.

> There are some other limitations like storage size etc

for ex: the maximum size for a single metafield value is typically 8KB

But there will be some limitations for sure as there is no such thing as unlimited.